Unable to verify the signature generated using Bouncy Castle in Java 17
So I had a code from Java 8 which is working fine for 3rd party API. Its properly generating the signature and verifying on client code but when I moved the same code to Java 17 it started giving error like

"message": "Curve not supported: secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)

After some research I came to know I might have to use Bouncy Castle for signature generation in Java 17 as this curve is not supported here but after adding bouncy castle its generating signature but its not getting verified on Client API not sure why
JAVA 8 Code:
public String sign(String payload) throws Exception {

    File keyFile = new File(privatekeyFilePath);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
    byte[] keyData = Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath());
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyData);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);

    ecdsa.initSign(privateKey);
    ecdsa.update(payload.getBytes());
    byte[] derSignature = ecdsa.sign();
    String signed = Base64.encode(derSignature);
    String headerValue = "ecdsa=" + signed;
    System.out.println("signed=" + headerValue);
    return headerValue;
}

Code in Java 17 which is not working properly
@RequestMapping(value = "/sign", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> signRequest(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestParams) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestParams);

            // Call the sign method with the JSON payload
            String signedRequest = sign(payload);
            response.put("signedRequest", signedRequest);
            response.put("status", "success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.put("status", "error");
            response.put("message", e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String sign(String payload) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Payload: " + payload);

        // Load the private key
        File keyFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keys/private-key.der").getFile());
        byte[] keyData = Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath());

        // Print the key data for debugging
        System.out.println("Private Key Data: " + Arrays.toString(keyData));

        // Create KeyFactory and PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "BC");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyData);

        // Generate the private key
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);

        // Print the private key for debugging
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + privateKey);

        // Initialize the Signature with SHA256withECDSA
        Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
        ecdsa.initSign(privateKey);

        // Sign the payload
        ecdsa.update(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] derSignature = ecdsa.sign();

        // Print the DER-encoded signature for debugging
        System.out.println("DER Signature: " + Arrays.toString(derSignature));

        // Encode the signature to Base64
        String signed = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derSignature);
        String headerValue = "ecdsa=" + signed;

        // Print the signed header value
        System.out.println("Signed Header Value: " + headerValue);
        return headerValue;
    }

Not sure what else I should do what are the resolutions to sort out. Given going back to older java version is not a solution.

On my machine, the sign() methods of the Java 8 and Java 17 code generate valid ASN.1/DER signatures that can be verified with the same verification code. Check the consistency of the data. Possibly the problem is with the JSON serialization, which is done differently on both sides, or not related private and public key etc.

There are basically no configuration options for this kind of signature scheme, so what Topaco mentions above is the expected outcome. Compare payload.getBytes("UTF-8") for signing and verification using hexadecimals and spot the differences. Don't encode & update the signature on the same line.
